# Configure weblogic to support modern authentication

Tags: java, web-services, office365, jms, weblogic

I have a weblogic that has the JMS configured to sniff an Office 365 mailbox to read the attachments of the mails. However after the modern authentication is activated I can no longer access the mailbox and the mails are not processed. My question is the following, how can I configure weblogic to do the authentication using the authentication token or alternatively which Java library can I use to be able to do this authentication?